# How do I pay for the download?

Tags: download

I live in India and I have only net banking facility from a local bank. How do I pay for the download? I do not have a credit card or any other method of paying.

Comment: Don't you have ATM cum debit card? If yes, it might work. Otherwise there is no way to make a payment. As Lewis said you my bypass the payment by adding 0.

Answer (score 1):

You can enter a zero to bypass the Stripe download if you cannot pay via credit/debit/bitcoin/alipay.

Comment: Maybe he wants to pay/donate

Comment: Possibly, but if they can't use one of the methods available then that's not an option.